# what's the meaning of "The highly anticipated..."?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

Last week the highly anticipated Cabrillo West opened in Palmesa Square

Answer (score 0):

The word "anticpated" doesn't sit well in the sentence. You might anticipate an *announcement* that a new store or venue will be opening, but once it is known, there is no anticipation.

I suggest other phrases:

> Last week the highly acclaimed Cabrillo West opened in Palmesa Square.

or

> Last week the long awaited Cabrillo West opened in Palmesa Square.

If you would still like to use "anticipated" I suggest (thanks to @Davo)

> Last week saw the highly anticipated opening of Cabrillo West in
>   Palmesa Square.

because it is an *event* which is anticipated, not a *thing*.

Comment: Also, *at* and not *in* Palmesa Square.

Comment: @MaulikV that is debatable. We say "in a street (or square)" here (British) but would say "at the beach".

Comment: At the time it *just opened*, it was still highly anticipated. And "on the square" is used in AmEng for a business which has the main entrance literally opening onto the square.

Comment: @Davo yes, it is the *opening* which is anticipated. Edited thank you.

Comment: I don't think [acclaimed](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/acclaim) has a similar meaning, since it implies "praise" rather than "eagerly looking forward to".